# GetEnabledMso: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba, ribbon

I have the following line of code:

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso("FileNewDefault")
```

where `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` is the `Excel.Application` object.  This code returns whether the ribbon control passed as the argument is enabled, and is used to check whether Excel is in edit mode.  It works fine most of the time, but  throws the following exception on a very small number of users' computers:

```
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

I do not have access to these computers to investigate further, and I am unable to reproduce the problem myself.  My intuition was that this could be because versions of Excel in different languages use different `idMso` values, or that the FileNewDefault `idMso` is not available in specific Excel versions (e.g. Excel 2007, 2010).  However, neither seems to be the case based on my limited testing.

Has anyone come across this before, or does anyone have ideas on what could be throwing this exception here?

Comment: Is the button visible when you call the method?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev In my testing on my dev PC it does not seem to matter whether the control is visible, and I have read in other places that it does not (although I don't recall where).